# Simple HTML DOM Parser convert &nbsp; in strange character

Tags: php, parsing, utf-8, simple-html-dom

I don't know for what reason but PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser converts `&nbsp;` fetched from the page into �. Do you happen to know why and how can I fix this?

I added this line at the top of my php file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I'm not using a database, I only paste the content on my screen.

Comment: it doesn't matter; go through it all

Comment: just replace all `&nbsp;` with a space